# Javascript: searching for a key to return a value

Tags: javascript

Hi am doing a in javascript: The data will be map. The key will be the search target. If you find that target in your data, return the value of that word and show it on your page.

I cannot get it search functionality to work. Like, if I want search for Harry, it should give me result "an old English word".

Any ideas for this to fix?

```js
function myfunction() {
  var data = new Map();
  data.set("Harry", "something.");
  data.set("Corhoo", "corn.");
  data.set("Elephant", "big ");

  var keys = Object.keys(data);

  //Need help with this loop, to get the search work
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    var key = keys[i];
    if (keys[i] == "Harry") {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = data.get("Harry");
    }
    //console.log(data[keys[i]]);
  }
}
```

```html
Enter: <input type="text" />
<p id="result"></p>
<p id="result2"></p>
<input type="button" value="SearchIt" onclick="myfunction()" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you want to use loop? It's better to use `Map.proptype.has` method:

```html
Enter: <input type="text" id="key"/>
<p id="result"></p>
<p id="result2"></p>
<input type="button" value="SearchIt" onclick="search()" />
```

```js
var data = new Map();
data.set("Harry", "An old English word that means Potter.");
data.set("Corhoo", "The Gaelic version of America Cornhole.");
data.set("Elephant", "A largest plant resembling an Ele");

function search(key) {

  var key = document.getElementById('key').value;
  var result = document.getElementById("result");

  if(data.has(key)) {
      result.innerHTML = data.get(key);
  } else {
      result.innerHTML = "No key found";
  }
}
```

Comment: What I a trying to do, it when I search any of the three keys, using if statement, it should only print out, the matching value of key. That is not working for me. So, if harry, print "An old English work, else if Corhoo, print "The Gaelic version", else if Elephant, print"A largest plant.  --- When I put all three if statements, it prints all values, even when I search Harry

Comment: @PTL, take a look at my edit. Is that you are looking for?

Comment: yes, this is exactly what I was trying to do. Tried all different ways, but wasn't getting the right way.  Thank you very much for you help.

Comment: Just FYI, if this worked best for you, you should mark it as the answer so others that find this thread know which one worked. I'm giving it an upvote for its elegance among other reasons.

Answer (score 1):

If you do console.log of `keys` from `var keys = Object.keys(data);` it will give an empty array. You may not need to do `Object.keys`

```js
function myfunction() {
  var data = new Map();
  data.set("Harry", "An old English word that means Potter.");
  data.set("Corhoo", "The Gaelic version of America Cornhole.");
  data.set("Elephant", "A largest plant resembling an Ele");
  if (data.has('Harry')) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = data.get("Harry");
  }
}
```

```html
Enter: <input type="text" />
<p id="result"></p>

<p id="result2"></p>

<input type="button" value="SearchIt" onclick="myfunction();" />
```

Comment: Yes, this work. But let say, I want to search Corhoo, and I put another if statement similar to harry to search for Corhoo, it doesn't work. it prints both of the values.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but this should work to map out the keys and return the value if the key is found.

```
const data = {
  'Harry': 'An old English word'
}

Object.keys(data).map(key => {
  if (key === 'Harry') {
    return data[key]
  }
}
```

ETA:

If using Map to create key-value pairs, use this instead:

```
data.forEach(item => {
  if(item[0] === 'Harry') {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = item[1]
    // or whatever you want to run if 'Harry' is found
  }
}
```

For searching a particular term:

```
const searchTerm = 'Harry'

data.forEach(item => {
  if(item[0] === searchTerm) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = item[1]
    // or whatever you want to run if 'Harry' is found
  }
}
```

Comment: It wouldn't give me the result. My original questions is: Create a page that does a search through your data to find the meaning of that word. The data will be map. They key will be the search target. If I find that target in my data, return the value of that word and show. So, if I search Harry, show value of Harry, if I search Corhoo- show value of that.

Comment: I'm not sure if you get a notification for an edit on an answer, but the update should answer your question using your Map data